# Keyboard shortcut added to lubuntu-rc.xml is not executed on keypress

Tags: shortcut-keys, lubuntu, openbox

I wanted to add a custom keyboard shortcut to control mplayer. mplayer config file is set up properly.

`~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioPlay">
    <action name="Execute">
        <command>echo "pause" > /home/username/.mplayer/pipe</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

Pressing the corresponding key has no effect.
Executing the command itself (`echo "pause" > /home/username/.mplayer/pipe` in terminal) works as expected.

Is there any way to check if the file is parsed and loaded correctly?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to run `openbox --reconfigure` from a terminal and look out for messages that may help you fix things.

Are you sure you've added this code within the `<keyboard>` and `</keyboard>` tags? If it's elsewhere, it will be ignored.

---

Looking at your code, with the **echo** in it, I'm not sure that Openbox does such stuff. You may not get an error so long as the xml structure and syntax is okay.
In case you don't get an answer here, you could sign up and ask here: http://icculus.org/mailman/listinfo/openbox. Devs hang out there and are helpful!

Comment: Hm, yeah, I think you're right. Tried it with another arbitrary command which works (`pcmanfm` in this case). Hmm I don't know enought about openbox or fifo files to troubleshoot this one. the mailinglist sounds good, might go check it out, thanks.